# Tradeoffs of different website caching architectures

Tags: language-agnostic, caching, memcached, distributed-caching

Are there any good articles or blog posts that explore the tradeoffs of different website caching architectures?

For example, what are the pros/cons of having a separate cache for each website host vs using consistent hashing to share the caches between each of the website hosts vs using a dedicated caching host? What about using one pattern for data that needs to be very consistent and another pattern for data that is high volume but doesn't necessarily need to be consistent.

Has the industry settled on a common pattern for most use cases?

Answer (score 0):

memcached is a LRU cache which means the Least Recently Used item is what get's the boot once it reaches it's maximum memory usage, and it gets a new item that it needs space for.

In practice, this means that it's best to just put all your data in the same memcached instance and let it keep whatever you ask for most often in memory and push out the least asked for items.